# javascript - prototype chain

Tags: javascript, prototype, chain

Please consider such a code:

```
class a {
    constructor() {
        this.test = "test from a";
        this.testA = "X";
    }

    mimi() {
        console.log('aaaaaaaa', this.test, this.testA)
    }

}

class b extends a {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.test = "test from b"
    }

    mimi() {
        console.log('bbbbbbbb', this.test, this.testA)
    }

}

class c extends b {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.test = "test from c"
    }

    mimi() {
        console.log('cccccccc', this.test, this.testA)
    }

    meme() {
        var test = kalreg.__proto__.__proto__;
        test.mimi();
        var test2 = kalreg.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__;
        test2.mimi();
    }
}

var kalreg = new c(); kalreg.mimi(); kalreg.meme();
```

The output I get is:

```
cccccccc test from c X
bbbbbbbb undefined undefined
aaaaaaaa undefined undefined
```

My object logic makes me use "**a**" as the most generic class, "**b**" that is a child to it, and "**c**" that is the child to "**b**". I want "**c**" to have all methods and properties of "**b**" and "a" BUT part of functionalities of "**a**" is overwritten by "**b**" so the only way "**c**" may have access to overwritten functionalities is to use prototype chain. 
Unfortunately, my way doesn't work so the questions are:

1. In `meme()` function, how to avoid kalreg.proto - I've been told that such way of accessing prototype is bad and dangerous for the code.
2. In my opinion, there should be no "undefined" in output, however, there is. 
   The expected output is:

   cccccccc test from c X

   bbbbbbbb test from b X

   aaaaaaaa test from a X

How to achieve it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in `meme() function`, how to avoid kalreg.**proto**

Use `super` for the use cases where you really do need to access a property from the superclass (but note that that won't help with `test` and `testA`, because those aren't on the superclass or its `prototype` object, they're on the instance created with `new c`; more on that below).

Separately: Avoid `__proto__`. In those rare cases where you need to access an object's prototype, use `Object.getPrototypeOf`.

> in my opinion there should be no "undefined" in output however there is. expected output is:
>
> cccccccc test from c X
>
> bbbbbbbb test from b X
>
> aaaaaaaa test from a X

The output is correct, because the prototype objects on which you're calling `mimi` don't have a `test` or `testA` property. Only the object created with `new c` has those properties. And there is only one such object, so `test` will be `"test from c"` no matter which `mimi` you call, and `testA` will always be `"X"`.

In a comment you've asked how there can only be one `test` when each constructor has `this.test = ...` in it. Let's look at what's in memory once you've done `var kalreg = new c();`:

```
                                         +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
a−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−>| (function) |  +−−−>(Function.prototype)
                                      |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
                                      |  | __proto__  |−−+          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                      |  | prototype  |−−−−−−−−−−+−>|  (object)   |
                                      |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−+          |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                      |                          |  | __proto__   |−−>...
                       +−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |                          |  | constructor |−−>a
b−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−>| (function) | |                          |  | mimi        |−−>...
                    |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |                          |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                    |  | __proto__  |−+         +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
                    |  | prototype  |−−−−−−−−+−>|  (object)   |  |
                    |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−+        |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
                    |                        |  | __proto__   |−−+
     +−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |                        |  | constructor |−−>b
c−−−>| (function) | |                        |  | mimi        |−−>...
     +−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |                        |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
     | __proto__  |−+        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |
     | prototype  |−−−−−−−+−>|  (object)   | |
     +−−−−−−−−−−−−+       |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |
                          |  | __proto__   |−+
                          |  | constructor |−−>c
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |  | mimi        |−−>...
kalreg−−−>|  (object)  |  |  | meme        |−−>...
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
          | __proto__  |−−+
          | test       |
          | testA      |
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

As you can see, only the object `kalreg` points to has `test` or `testA`. Why? Because during the call to each constructor, `this` refers to that object; that's how `new` and `super()` work. So since `this` refers to that object, each constructor does its `this.test = ...` line, and since the one in `c` is the last one to run, it "wins."

You can access superclass versions of the `mimi` method, but since they all show the `test` property, they'll all show `"test from c"`. To show different things, they'd have to have *different* properties to show. Additionally, with `super` you can only go one level up, so if you wanted to go two levels up, you'd either use `a.prototype.mimi` (or `this.__proto__.__proto__.mimi` explicitly, or put some facility in `b` to call `a`'s `mimi`.

Example with different properties for each level, and with `b` providing `superMimi` so `c` can use `a`'s `mimi`:

```js
class a {
    constructor() {
        this.testA = "test from a (this.testA)";
    }

    mimi() {
        console.log('aaaaaaaa', this.testA);
    }
}

class b extends a {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.testB = "test from b (this.testB)";
    }

    mimi() {
        console.log('bbbbbbbb', this.testB)
    }
    
    superMimi() {
      return super.mimi();
    }
}

class c extends b {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.testC = "test from c (this.testC)";
    }

    mimi() {
        console.log('cccccccc', this.testC);
    }

    meme() {
        super.mimi();      // Uses b's version
        super.superMimi(); // Uses a's version
        this.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.mimi.call(this); // Also uses a's version
        var p = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
        var p2 = Object.getPrototypeOf(p);
        var p3 = Object.getPrototypeOf(p2);
        p3.mimi.call(this); // Also uses a's version
    }
}

var kalreg = new c();
kalreg.mimi();
kalreg.meme();
```

Comment: How objects may not have this.test if every class have this.test defined in their constructor?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to use `super` to accomplish the OPs goal in the `meme()` method.

Comment: @Adam: Done, thanks for flagging it up, I meant to circle back to that and forgot. :-)

Comment: @Kalreg: I've added the picture and a bit more explanation.